# change value of yes/no field in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a field of type Yes/No (checkbox) in my sharepoint list. 
I am trying to change/set the value of the field programmatically (server code), but it give me an error saying that it should be 1 or 0. I cannot get it working. Can anyone help me please?

here that part of the code:

```
 SPListItem item = reportList.Items.Add();
                item["RequesterID"] = id;

                 **item["ZIP_x0020_Code_x0020_Linked"] = 0;**

                item["ZC_x0020_code"] = txtZcCode.Text;
                item.Update();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a Yes/No field, you should set it to "1" or "0":

```
item["ZIP_x0020_Code_x0020_Linked"] = "0";
```

Look here for more info:

http://blog.henryong.com/2008/12/05/programmatically-setting-the-default-value-of-a-spfieldboolean-field/

Comment: Garrett, thanks for the reply. I have tried it as well but no luck.I have seen the link as well but it is not helping me. this is the error that I am getting:

A Yes/No field contains invalid data. It should be either 1 or 0. Please check the value and try again.

Comment: Can you check your field definition and make sure the DEFAULT value is set to 1 or 0?  That could be causing the issue.

Comment: @IH-77 try so set value as int `item["ZIP_x0020_Code_x0020_Linked"] = 0;`

Comment: The problem solved. All the suggestions are right. The problem was actually with another field which was set to required and I was not using it in the code. So when ever I tried to update the list item via code it gave me that error which was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For a Yes/No field, you can set it to "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using sharepoint online version, the only way i was able to update the field is by using ParseAndSetFieldValue ListItem method.

```
 // Using ParseAndSetFieldValue instead of setting directly
 item.ParseAndSetFieldValue("FIELDNAME", "true"); // to set field to true
 item.ParseAndSetFieldValue("FIELDNAME", "false"); // to set field to false
 item.Update();
 // IF Content Approval is enabled on library / list
 item.File.Approve("Approval message.");
 // Needed to popuplate changes to sharepoint server.
 spContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hopes this helps. I've added this answer even the question is marked as solved because it didn't work in my case.